# Basics on lattice in classical groups

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homogeneous-spaces

as a beginner,I am not sure whether this question is too basic to post here./-\。

Many textbook will talk about the prototypical example SL(n,Z)\SL(n,R), which can be identified with the space of unimodular lattices. But for PGL(n,Z)\PGL(n,R), less is said about. Also, I am not sure GL(n,Z) is a lattice in GL(n,R) or not.

Okay, I will turn to the question. Does there exist some approaches to determine whether a discrete subgroup in a classical group is a lattice and how to construct a fundamental domain. If possible, could you please give me some references? Thanks!

Comment: The determinant maps $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ to $\{\pm 1\}$, so it is not a lattice in $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$. About references: as a beginner you may enjoy the book by Dave Witte-Morris:
http://people.uleth.ca/%7Edave.morris/books/IntroArithGroups.html

Answer (score 2):

As Alain says, in your specific example, it is easy to tell that $GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ is *not* a lattice in $GL(n, \mathbb{R}).$ In general, in many interesting cases it is easy to [check whether your discrete is Zariski dense](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.3009) (that paper has many relevant references), but checking whether a subgroup is co-finite volume is almost certainly undecidable, except in rank 1, where the Poincare polyhedron theorem (which google, or see Brian Bowditch's thesis) is your friend. For the latter, see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181868/dirichlet-polyhedra-for-hyperbolic-manifolds) and Misha's answer to it.

Comment: Igor: I do not think there is a known algorithm to decide if a subgroup is not a lattice (the other direction is OK), even for subgroups of $SL(2,C)$. But, there is an algorithm to check that a subgroup is not arithmetic (assuming its generators have matrix coefficients from some number field).